# Define a variable for use as chart title and filename

Tags: excel, vba

I managed to solve my problem, so I am updating my code in case anyone stumbles on something similar. (Problem was: I have multiple sheets and I did not specify that in my code)

---

I open a csv file in Excel. I want the string in cell C1 to be stored as, say, FILE, and to use it for:

1. Save my Excel file as "FilePath...\FILE.xlsm"
2. Plot some graphs (time series data) and give to each a title of the form "Mean values of FILE"

Here the code

```
Sub OpenCvs()
'Open Cvs with right formats

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\medeossie\Documents\CariParma\SAS\Corporate\corANA01.csv", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "corANA01"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(4, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Plot Charts

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$B$1"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$61"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$61"
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet2"

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$C$1"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$61"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$61"
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet2"

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$D$1"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$D$2:$D$61"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$61"
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet2"


'Lining up Charts

Dim MyWidth As Single, MyHeight As Single
Dim NumWHigh As Long
Dim iChtIx As Long, iChtCt As Long

MyWidth = 400
MyHeight = 300
NumHigh = 3

iChtCt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
For iChtIx = 1 To iChtCt
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iChtIx)
     .Width = MyWidth
     .Height = MyHeight
     .Left = ((iChtIx - 1) Mod NumHigh) * MyWidth
     .Top = Int((iChtIx - 1) / NumHigh) * MyHeight
End With
Next

'Saving file
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename _
    :="C:\Users\medeossie\Documents\CariParma\SAS\Corporate\" & Range("Sheet1!C1") & ".xlsm", FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Plenty of examples around for [how to do this](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+graph+title+named+variable&safe=active&ssui=on). What have you tried and can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: We would love to see the _everything else_ around where you want to use the variable as file name

Answer (score 1):

You will need a string type variable that can have some text assigned to it. You will have to work within the chart object properties to get at the title.

This is a fairly rudimentary example but you should be able to see where the presence and content of a chart title is determined. I'll leave in several others so you can see how things like positioning and source data are involved.

```
Dim cht As Chart, sTitle as String
sTitle = "My New Chart Title"
Set cht = Charts.Add
Set cht = cht.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1")
With cht
    .ChartType = xl3DPie
    ' lots of other chart definition stuff here
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$9")
    .HasLegend = False
    With .Parent
        .Name = "My_New_Chart"
        .Top = Range("M5").Top
        .Left = Range("M5").Left
        .Width = Range("M5:Q20").Width
        .Height = Range("M5:Q20").Height
    End With
    ' the next two have to do with the chart title
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = sTitle 
End With
```

With regard to saving the worksheet, you really need to know what worksheet you are drawing the filename from in C1. ActiveSheet may be oh-key-doh-key here *most* on the time but defining the worksheet with the filename by worksheet name or codename would be better. I'll assume a worksheet named **SheetOne**.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
  Filename:="C:\Users\medeossie\Documents\CariParma\SAS\Corporate\" & Sheets("SheetOne").Range("C1").Value & ".xlsm", _
  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

That looks correct for the [Workbook.SaveAs Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129(v=office.12).aspx) although I probably wouldn't bother with the *CreateBackup:=False* since false is the default. Illegal filename characters in the value in Sheets("SheetOne").Range("C1") is another possible trouble area.

Comment: Well, I managed to use the variable as title for all my charts, so thank you. As for saving my worksheet, I am having some troubles. I have read many threads in which the problem is solved using the following lines, but this does not work for me.

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\medeossie\Documents\CariParma\SAS\Corporate\" & Range("C1").Value & ".xlsm", FileFormat _
        :=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

When I run my code I get a 1004 error (method 'SaveAs' of object'_workbook' failed.

Comment: That looks correct for the [Workbook.SaveAs Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129(v=office.12).aspx) although I wouldn't bother with the *CreateBackup:=False* since false is the default. You're saving locally but if that is not your own profile folder make sure that you have the requisite permissions to save there. Of course, a lot depends on what is in C1 (possible illegal file name characters) but you haven't offered that bit of information. I suspect that the code doesn't know what worksheet C1 is on. See my edit above.